# MobileConnect Blockout Window setting is not honored, for Journeys with Entry Source as API

Tags: api, journeybuilder, mobileconnect, sms

We are re-working on our campaign due to the recent regulations set by the Malaysian government. According to the new rules, sending SMS messages between 11 PM and 8 AM is prohibited.

Currently, our journeys are triggered using the Interaction - Fire Entry Event API, which allows us to pass Contact Key, EventDefinitionKey, and Data information. Unfortunately, there is no provision to set up BlockoutWindow JSON parameters for this API, similar to what we can do for SMS using the Post Message to Number API.

After conducting some test and consulting Salesforce support and articles, I have made the following observations:

1. If the entry source for a Journey is an API, the MobileConnect > Administration > Blockout Window setting is not respected. Customers will still receive SMS messages even if the API trigger occurs during the blockout window.
2. However, when the entry source for a Journey is a Data Extension, the Blockout Window is honored, and SMS messages are queued and sent after the blockout window expires.
3. Setting the blackout window in the SMS Activity within Journey Builder will not queue the SMS; instead, it prevents the SMS from being sent at all.

I am seeking assistance in finding a workaround that allows us to identify the real-time sending time of the API and queue SMS messages (add wait by duration until specific time) when the API is triggered -

Two points to consider:

1. We have both SMS and Email communications in our journeys, and customers receive messages based on their preferences. We want to avoid creating two separate journeys across multiple campaigns, as customer preferences may change during the campaigns, we need an integrated solution.
2. The API call originates from an external Loyalty system, and unfortunately, they are unable to provide the exact hour or a flag indicating the time the API call was sent.

Thank you for your attention and any help you can provide with this matter.

Comment: there is no queuing of messages during a blackout window

Comment: Thanks @EazyE - yup we have exhausted all options and we probably would have to change our API calls to a scheduled one or remove SMS altogether from it. shooting in the dark here to see if anyone has come up with some creative solutions :D for real time APIs.